# How to select data for xml Element with specific attribute value wiith multiple elements distinguished based on key?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Given:

> using xml.etree.ElementTree

```
<stream>
    <max id="500">
        <bar id="233" value="hell"/>
        <bar id="234" value="hello"/>
    </max>
</stream>
```

I want to get the text for the 'value attribute' in max element where the key attribute 'id = 234'

How do i obtain this?
One solution is ,

> for fieldvalue in streams.findall('./max/bar'):
>
> ```
>    xmlKeyValue = fieldvalue.get('id')
>
>    if xmlKeyValue == "234":
>
>        sol  = fieldvalue.get('value')
>
>        print sol
> ```

Is there any better solution to it? one liner solution?

Comment: Your `xml` data is not well formed. You should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

One way using [beautifulsoup](/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup):

```
print(soup.find('stream').find('max').find('bar', attrs={'id':'234'})['value'])
```

It yields:

```
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do in with [lxml](/questions/tagged/lxml) and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
from lxml import etree

xml = """
<stream>
    <max id="500">
        <bar id="233" value="hell"/>
        <bar id="234" value="hello"/>
    </max>
</stream>"""

xml = etree.fromstring(xml)
print xml.xpath('//max/bar[@id=234]/@value')  # ['hello']
```